# Extract String in Data Class Kotlin

Tags: android, string, kotlin, localization, android-room

I have a data class something like:

```
class Person {
    var name: String
    var title: String
}
```

And I give some values which are inserted at a database using room (for example `Person("John","Vicepresident")` and `Person("Martha","President")`. I am wondering if there is any way I can extract strings like "Vicepresident" and "President" in an xml file and after that using different localization files.

Extract strings usually need context which i am not able to use out of a function.

Comment: You don't need any context to extract string from anywhere and add it to strings.xml file

Comment: you can't change xml files at runtime and you definitely shouldn't even if a solution for this exists

Comment: It is not the idea to change the xml file at runtime. Just when you localize your app, the os select the proper xml file to use the strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use their integer value to store in database. So, instead of name: String you can use name: Int and give name as Person("John", R.string.vice_president) and Person("Martha", R.string.president) . Whenever you want to get you can use it in the activity like :

```
val person = Person()

getString(person.name)
```